# selecting multiple criteria in R (bis)

Tags: r

I come back with a question for which i had an answer working on an example, but not on my data. From the data.frame "data" proposed below, with individuals (id) tested 3 times (T = 1, 2 or 3), i would like to build a new data.frame "data2" containing the individuals for who the value of the Y variable is "yes" at all three time points.

```
> data <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:10), 3),
                 T  = gl(3, 10),
                 X  = sample(1:30),
                 Y  = sample(c("yes", "no"), 30, replace = TRUE),
                 Z  = sample(1:40, 30),
                 Z2 = rnorm(30, mean = 5, sd = 0.5))

> head(data)
  id T  X   Y  Z       Z2
1  1 1 10 yes 15 5.993605
2  2 1 18  no 22 6.096566
3  3 1  5  no 24 5.101393
4  4 1 15 yes 18 4.944108
5  5 1 23  no 34 4.634176
6  6 1 13  no 27 5.576015
```

Instead of following a good proposition, but that didn't really worked, i would like to select separately the rows where Y is "yes" when T=="1", and then do the same for T=="2" and T=="3". Like that :

```
> data1y <- subset(data, T=="1"&Y=="yes")
   > data2y <- subset(data, T=="2"&Y=="yes")
    > data3y <- subset(data, T=="3"&Y=="yes")
```

At that point, i would have to match "id" from these 3 data.frames and keep only those that match on all three data.frame, putting them back into a new data.frame. 
Can someone help me for this last step?
Thanks

Comment: i opened this new question on the advice of someone on the forum. Why -2??

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. This question is identical to your previous question.

Comment: I dont understand the difference it mkes but ok. So how can i bring back an old question that had not any good solution, despite helpful tips?

Comment: The answers in your previous Q were better than these here.

Comment: You admitted that my solution to your previous (identical) question was correct: that it worked for the example you provided, but that it did not work with your real data. I suggested you give a small example of your real data, with whatever makes my answer not specific enough. Yet, you have posted here the same question with the same sample data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample data:

```
> data[data$T %in% c(1:3) & data$Y=='yes',]
   id T  X   Y  Z             Z2
1   1 1 20 yes 33 4.802216126170
5   5 1 11 yes 38 4.961652111819
6   6 1 16 yes 39 5.280062964072
8   8 1  9 yes 10 4.390774184018
10 10 1  2 yes 24 5.304658353230
11  1 2 28 yes 16 5.431195694915
12  2 2 10 yes 14 4.719670597678
13  3 2 27 yes  3 4.568885260296
14  4 2  4 yes 32 5.699626145087
15  5 2 19 yes 21 5.378941823200
17  7 2  5 yes 34 5.144265923191
18  8 2  1 yes  8 5.138866423019
19  9 2 29 yes 35 5.938777921967
20 10 2 18 yes 30 5.562200417288
24  4 3  6 yes 23 4.723790836659
26  6 3 25 yes 29 5.915660736770
28  8 3  8 yes 19 5.133772600848
```

If that doesn't sort you, leave a comment...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, matey...

Comment: I think they are looking for one additional step. Something like `data1[data1$id %in% names(which(table(data1$id) == 3)), ]` where `data1` is your `data.frame` above.

Comment: Thank you hd1 AND Ananda Mahto : your answers complement perfectly each other and work very well.

Comment: QUESTION on this : why is there a "," at the end of both of your conditional expressions ? thank you !!

Comment: Because if you don't have it, it gives "undefined columns selected".